# Updating outlook search folder filter programmatically using Redemption

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

Outlook search folder can be created as following with specific name

```
var advancedSearch = OutlookApp.AdvancedSearch(scope, filter, true, advancedSearchTag );     
advancedSearch.Save(folderName);
```

but if I need to update the filter, I have to delete and recreate the folder. Sometimes the folder can not be deleted properly.

How to update search folder filter using outlook-redemption as similar way ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of the `RDOSession` object, set its `MAPIOBJECT` property to `Namespace.MAPIOBJECT` from OOM (to ensure the the two share the same MAPI session), and access existing search folders through either `RDOStore2.Searches` or through `RDOStore.SearchRootFolder`.

You can then use either `RDOSearch.SearchCriteria.AsSQL` or `RDOSearchFolder.SearchCriteria.AsSQL`